# Why is sequelize.define() not a function when I try to run it in a model of mine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, sequelize.js

So I'm new to discord.js/node.js and I'm trying to make a bot with a currency system. When I try to run my `deploy-commands.js` file, however, it tells me `sequelize.define() is not a function` in my `Users.js` file. I've read other questions which say that it's because I need to call `define()` on an instance of sequelize rather than sequelize itself, but I've tried making an instance for it to call and it seems to give the same error. I have the feeling I'm not correctly creating an instance of sequelize, but if that's true then I would probably be at a loss since I've tried following other answers to this question to no avail.

my `Users.js` file:

```js
const { sequelize } = require('../index.js').sequelize;

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('users', {
        user_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            primaryKey: true,
        },
        balance: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0,
            allowNull: false,
        },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
    });
};
```

my `deploy-commands.js` file:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, token } = require('./config.json');
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize');

const commands = [];
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

`my index.js file:`

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const {Sequelize, DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS] });

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    // SQLite only
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

module.exports = { sequelize };

client.commands = new Collection();

const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}

const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection
    // With the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.login(token);
```

Comment: in your first code block you require your index and access the `.sequelize` key, but are already deconstructing `{ sequelize }` from the module, If I'm correcr that evaluates to `sequelize.sequelize`. Additionally you export a function that accepts a parameter named `sequelize` which can shadow your existing definition of "sequelize".

Comment: To put that into perspective, what will be the value of `sequelize` in your exported function? The required variable (which is conflicted) or the value being passed in (which may be shadowed)